# How to speed up my beautifulsoup4 webscraper

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I'm working on a smaller project to fill in my GitHub and learn more about web scraping so my end goal here is to scrape some of the more popular brands of watches off a watch marketplace. I've gotten to a point where I can get some data in arrays, but I've noticed that by the time I start to scrape more data, it would take way too long. Any advice for speeding up this script?

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
chrono24 = 'https://www.chrono24.com'

single_watch_url = 'https://www.chrono24.com/rolex/rolex-rolex-gmt-master-ii-batman-oyster-bracelet-126710blnr-2023--id20505792.htm'
watch_list_url = 'https://www.chrono24.com/rolex/index.htm'

def parse_watch_page(url):
    """
    function to parse a single watch page
    :param url: url to a singular watch page
    :return: a list of descriptor/info tuples
    """

    # get page as bs4 html parser
    html = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    page = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'lxml')
    
    # searches for table that contains "Basic Info" text
    basic_info_table = page.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name =='tbody' and "Basic Info" in tag.text)[0]
    # gets rows of basic info table
    table_rows = basic_info_table.find_all('tr')

    # parses each row for td tags and puts pairings into lists
    datalist = []
    for row in table_rows:
        elements = row.find_all('td')
        test = tuple([element.text.strip() for element in elements])
        datalist.append(test)
    datalist.pop(0)
    return datalist

def parse_watch_list(url):
    """
    function to parse a watch list page
    :param url: url to a page to a list of watches and next button
    :return: link to next?
    """

    # get page as bs4 html parser
    html = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    page = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'lxml')

    # finds all links to watches on the list
    watches = page.find_all('a', 'article-item block-item rcard')
    # parses each watch page
    for watch in watches:
        parse_watch_page(chrono24 + watch['href'])

parse_watch_list(watch_list_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1. use `concurrent`. If you don't even care about reporting those results one by one, you can even use `executor.map` to write more elegant code. https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map

```py
def parse_watch_list(url):
    """
    function to parse a watch list page
    :param url: url to a page to a list of watches and next button
    :return: link to next?
    """

    # get page as bs4 html parser
    html = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    page = BeautifulSoup(html.content, "lxml")

    # finds all links to watches on the list
    watches = page.find_all("a", "article-item block-item rcard")

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
        futures = [
            executor.submit(parse_watch_page, chrono24 + watch["href"])
            for watch in watches
        ]

        for _ in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            # I don't why you don't collect yoru results, so I won't neither.
            pass


parse_watch_list(watch_list_url)
```

2. Try `aiohttp`, and then execute your spiders with `await asyncio.gather(tasks)`

By all means, don't worry about the performance of your spider. Your spider is honestly comparatively fast enough for most use cases, as it does the bare-minimal HTTP requests necessary to get the data.